# Parallelise in snakemake using bioconductor, a singularity container and slurm

Tags: r, containers, slurm, snakemake, bioconductor

When running bioconductor packages in my snakemake pipelines on our computer cluster, I create bespoke singularity containers with the bioconductor packages I need. This has worked smoothly so far running processes that are not resource hungry.

I'm currently using a bioconductor package called tradeSeq, which uses `BiocParallel` to parallelise jobs for the functions `fitGAM()` and `evalualteK()`. Here is a snippet of the relevant R code I use to run this:

```
# Set resources
message('Setting seed and workers ...')
set.seed(10) # fitGAM is stochastic
message('Cores avaialable on Hawk: ', parallel::detectCores())
BPPARAM <- BiocParallel::bpparam()
BPPARAM$workers <- 20 # use 20 cores
BPPARAM # lists current options

# Get Knots
message('Getting knots ...')
aicMat <- evaluateK(counts = counts(shi_sce), pseudotime = pseudotime, cellWeights = cellWeights
                    , k = 3:20, nGenes = 500, verbose = TRUE, plot = TRUE, parallel = TRUE)

# Run fitGAM
message('Running fitGAM ...')
shi_sce <- fitGAM(counts = counts(shi_sce), pseudotime = pseudotime, cellWeights = cellWeights,
                  nknots = 7, verbose = FALSE, parallel = T, genes = var_genes)
```

My issue is that it's not clear to me how align the `BiocParallel` resource assignment with the resources I have specified via Slurm / snakemake. When running my R script I get the following error:

```bash
Error in reducer$value.cache[[as.character(idx)]] <- values : 
  wrong args for environment subassignment
Calls: evaluateK ... .bploop_impl -> .collect_result -> .reducer_add -> .reducer_add
```

Here is my snake rule:

```py
rule slingshot:
    input:  "../results/01R_objects/seurat_shi_bc.rds",
    output: "../results/01R_objects/sce_shi_bc.rds", 
    singularity: "../resources/containers/slingshot_latest.sif"
    resources: tasks = 1, mem_mb = 100000, threads = 21, nodes = 1
    params: results_dir = "../results/"
    log:    "../results/00LOG/06trajectory_inference/slingshot.log"
    script:
            "../scripts/snRNAseq_GE_slingshot.R"
```

And my snakemake profile config:

```
snakefile: Snakefile
cores: 1
#use-conda: True
use-singularity: True
keep-going: True
jobs: 10
rerun-incomplete: True
restart-times: 1
cluster:
  mkdir -p ../results/00LOG/smk-logfiles &&
  sbatch
    --qos=maxjobs500
    --ntasks={resources.tasks}
    --mem={resources.mem_mb}
    --time={resources.time}
    --cpus-per-task={resources.threads}
    --job-name=smk-{rule}
    --output=../results/00LOG/smk-logfiles/{rule}.%j.out
    --error=../results/00LOG/smk-logfiles/{rule}.%j.err
    --account=scw1641

default-resources:
  - ntasks=1
  - mem_mb=5000
  - time="3-00:00:00"
```

I have tried using `MulticoreParam()` and `SnowParam()` in BiocParallel.

The other option I've explored is using Bioconductor's `batchtools` using the following in my R script:

```
BatchtoolsParam(workers = 20, cluster = "slurm", template = tmpl)
```

But I'm not sure how to obtain an address for the slurm script that is spawned by snakemake to pass to the `template` parameter in the `BatchtoolsParam` function. Or if this is the best course of action.

When I run the `BatchtoolsParam(workers = 20, cluster = "slurm")`, so omitting the template parameter altogether, instead of the `BPPARAM$workers` line in the above R code I get the following error:

```bash
Setting seed and workers ...
Cores avaialable on Hawk: 40
Error in BatchtoolsParam(workers = 20, cluster = "slurm") : 
  'slurm' supported but not available on this machine
```

This suggests that despite snakemake scheduling the R script to the slurm cluster, slurm is not being detected within R when the script is running, and perhaps that the template file is necessary.

I've also tried running the script interactively, so bypassing snakemake altogether, using `batchtools` within the container. The `fitGAM()` function runs, but the jobs does not appear to being parallelised properly.

Any suggestions on how to efficiently parallelise Bioconductor processes within a container using Snakemake / Slurm would be greatly appreciated.